# CSS stopping from having text and input side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the style sheet which I am using :

```
/*custom font*/
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

    /*basic reset*/
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

    html {
        height: 100%;
        /*Image only BG fallback*/
        background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
        /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
        background: 
            linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
            url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
    }

    body {
        font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
    }

    /*form styles*/
    #msform {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        font-family: montserrat;
        color: #2C3E50;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    #msform fieldset {
        background: white;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        padding: 20px 30px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 10%;

        /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
        position: absolute;
    }


    /*For the table*/
    #msform table {
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: montserrat;
        color: #2C3E50;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    /*Hide all except first fieldset*/
    #msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
        display: none;
    }
    /*inputs*/
    #msform input, #msform textarea {
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: montserrat;
        color: #2C3E50;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    /*buttons*/
    #msform .action-button {
        width: 100px;
        background: #27AE60;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 1px;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        margin: 10px 5px;
    }
    #msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
    }
    /*headings*/
    .fs-title {
        font-size: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #2C3E50;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .fs-subtitle {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #666;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    /*progressbar*/
    #progressbar {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
        counter-reset: step;
    }
    #progressbar li {
        list-style-type: none;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 9px;
        width: 33.33%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    #progressbar li:before {
        content: counter(step);
        counter-increment: step;
        width: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #333;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
    }
    /*progressbar connectors*/
    #progressbar li:after {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: -50%;
        top: 9px;
        z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
    }
    #progressbar li:first-child:after {
        /*connector not needed before the first step*/
        content: none; 
    }
    /*marking active/completed steps green*/
    /*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
    #progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
        background: #27AE60;
        color: white;
    }
```

When I try to use lists/ tables and use something in the below format, the text and the input type(Radio/checkbox) are going to the next line instead of aligning side by side. How can I chang

```
<ul>

    <li>Facebook <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
    <li>Twitter <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
    <li>Instagram <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
    <li>Tumblr <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
    <li>Pinterest <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
    <li>Flickr <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
    <li>Others, Please specify. <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
</ul>
```

Attaching the screenshot of how it is looking. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you're setting  `width: 100%;` on all input fields (including checkboxes).

Comment: Just so you know, radio buttons, inputs, etc. will always create a line break unless you specify you want them on the same line. If you take the CSS out of this fiddle, it will better demonstrate that.. http://jsfiddle.net/5ww5p/1/

Comment: What size browser was this taken on?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast   It is My laptop's 17 Inch screen. Normal browser size

Comment: @DanielBeck So? How can I change the things

Comment: I think we are missing something here... http://jsfiddle.net/5ww5p/2/ Because the link shows that your check boxes are coming in normal.

Comment: That is what I am thinking... need a demo link to make sure

Comment: @kingmakerking So... If you don't want your checkboxes wrapping to the next line, don't set their width to the full width of the line.  i.e. remove the "width:100%" from your css. Apologies, I didn't realize I'd have to spell that out quite so verbosely.  (@BuddhistBeast their CSS is all under `#msform` which isn't present in the html as given, I assume it's elsewhere in their code.  http://jsfiddle.net/U9L5S/ with `#msform` added and with the `width:100%` removed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `checkbox` on the same line as the text on your page:

Remove: `width:100%;` from `#msform input, #msform textarea`

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3u3U/2/)

Comment: Actually I didn't solve the issue. Because, it listed the li elements side by side. I was wondering why the checkbox is going down.

Comment: `Table` will be a little more complicated :) you will have to use `tr` and `td` and style accordingly

Comment: Actually I didn't solve the issue. Because, it listed the li elements side by side. I was wondering why the checkbox is going down.

Comment: Did you want checkbox beside text?

Comment: Yes Yes I want checkbox beside text

Comment: Can you post your demo link so I can make sure before updating

Answer (score 2):

Expanding my comment above into an answer:

This will cause the checkbox to wrap to the next line, because it causes the checkbox to be as wide as the parent container:

```
input {width:100%}
<li>Facebook <input type="checkbox" name="SocialAccount" value="Facebook"></li>
```

If you want to apply width:100% to text input fields and textareas, you almost always will want to override that for checkbox and radio buttons:

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {width:auto}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DdH92/